# MongoDB query condition including SUM

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How I write this sql query with mongo?

```
select * from a where b + c < 5?
```

Comment: Search engines are your friend: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Comment: You also need to watch the "autotag" feature of StackOverflow. Cross posting to "sql" and a "nosql" tag is not going to win you friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`$redact`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is your best option:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$lt": [ { "$add": [ "$b", "$c" ] }, 5 ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "a": 1 } }
])
```

The logical condition is made via [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) on the math expression of [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) in order to determine which items to keep.

The [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) selects the fields.

The alternate is [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) which uses JavaScript evalution. Not as effective due to the JavaScript translation required ( the following is a shell shortcut for `$where` ):

```js
db.collection.find(
  function() {
    return ( this.b + this.c ) < 5;
  },
  { "_id": 0, "a": 1 }
);
```

Or:

```js
db.collection.find(
    { "$where": "return ( this.b + this.c ) < 5;" },
    { "_id": 0, "a": 1 }
);
```

Which is basically the same thing.

Native operators are more performant than JavaScript evalutation.